# inArray bidimensional doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a bidimensional array, and I'm trying to remove duplicates, I'm trying to do it with jquery function inArray.

This is my array:

```
var myArray = [ { data1 : "01" , data2 : "02" },  
                { data1 : "01" , data2 : "03" },
                { data1 : "01" , data2 : "02" } ];
var newData = { data1 : "01" , data2 : "02" };

console.log($.inArray(newData, myArray));
   -1
```

How can I compare this?

Comment: And what is the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [inArray](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/):
>
> Search for a specified value within an array and return its index (or -1 if not found).

Because you want to [grep](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/)/search for objects the best method is always:

```
JSON.stringify(elementOfArray) == JSON.stringify(newData)
```

So, in jQuery you can filter or grep all elements with the same content:

```js
var myArray = [{data1: "01", data2: "02"},
               {data1: "01", data2: "03"},
               {data1: "01", data2: "02"}];
var newData = {data1: "01", data2: "02"};

var result = $.grep(myArray, function (elementOfArray, indexInArray) {
  return JSON.stringify(elementOfArray) == JSON.stringify(newData);
});

console.log(result.length);


newData = {data1: "01", data2: "03"};
result = $.grep(myArray, function (elementOfArray, indexInArray) {
  return JSON.stringify(elementOfArray) == JSON.stringify(newData);
});

console.log(result.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It can not work because the object is different... For example it would work doing it like this :

```js
var myArray = [ { data1 : "01" , data2 : "02" },  
                { data1 : "01" , data2 : "03" },
                { data1 : "01" , data2 : "02" } ];
var newData = myArray[0];

console.log($.inArray(newData, myArray));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The only thing you can do is comparing the objects properties by properties (or add an id on each object and compare the ids for example)...

You can also just serialize the data you want to compare and use the findIndex method of the Array prototype.

```js
var myArray = [
  {data1: "01", data2: "02"},
  {data1: "01", data2: "03"},
  {data1: "01", data2: "02"},
  {data1: "01", data2: "03"},
  {data1: "01", data2: "03"},
  {data1: "01", data2: "03"},
  {data1: "01", data2: "03"},
  {data1: "01", data2: "03"},
  {data1: "01", data2: "03"},
];
var data = {data1: "01", data2: "02"};

// Using jQuery's grep method 
console.time("time1")
var result = $.grep(myArray, function (element) {
  return JSON.stringify(element) == JSON.stringify(data);
});
console.timeEnd("time1");
console.log(result.length);

// Using Array's prototype findIndex method
console.time("time2")
result = myArray.findIndex(function(element){
 return JSON.stringify(element) == JSON.stringify(data);
})
console.timeEnd("time2");
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It's better to use the built-in findIndex method if your browser supports it because it finds the first occurence and stops looping through the other items so it's more efficient. Hope it helps